# Is there a way to go back to a keyboard macro from elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have been creating macros and saving them for later use with the following process.

1. Create keyboard macro
2. Edit the macro: `C-x C-k C-e`
3. Name the macro: `M-x name-last-kbd-macro`
4. Create an .el file then insert the macro definition: `M-x insert-kbd-macro`

With the lisp code saved for later, I'll load it up in my `.emacs` file.  Perhaps it is my unfamiliarity with elisp, but the elisp code which is generated seems quite unwieldy.  I much prefer the syntax in the macro editor, and I'd like to make updates and refinements to the code that I've created, so I ask:

Is there a way to take my elisp code back to a reasonable rendition in the macro editor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `C-x C-k e M-x` followed by the name of the macro you want to edit. (Or `C-x C-k e` (`edit-kbd-macro`) followed by the key sequence a macro is bound to; `M-x` here is just a kind of mnemonic, as the help for the command explains).

Maybe it's also helpful to know that all the keyboard macros you've run are saved in a global ring, so you can cycle backwards and forwards through them using `C-x C-k C-n` and `C-x C-k C-p`.

BTW, it's not just unfamiliarity with Elisp that makes those macro definitions hard to read; `insert-kbd-macro` basically just writes out the macro as a vector of key sequences. Elisp written by humans is a much pleasanter language ;-)